# error: ISO C forbids nested functions|

Tags: c

```
bool winner(char c,int n,char m[n][n])
{
    if(Line(c,n,m))
        return true;

    if(column(c,n,m))
        return true;

    if(Radios1(c,n,m))
        return true;

    if(Radios2(c,n,m))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

and i got this error .what is the problem?

Comment: I'm guessing one of those things that looks like a function is actually a macro expanding to something else. It's hard to say from the code you've shown what's wrong, but you could write this function much more simply with use of the `||` operator.

Comment: Possibly one of the functions preceding this one is missing a closing bracket (`}`).

Comment: You'll need to show the rest of the code.

Comment: I don't get that error. That can't be your entire source file; you'll get errors on `bool`, `false`, and `true` unless you add `#include <stdbool.h>`.

Comment: I can't get that error, if I have a missing bracket, I get `error: expected declaration or statement at end of input`, and if I make a nested C function with `gcc -std=c99` it still compiles fine…

Comment: @zmo: The diagnostic for nested functions doesn't appear unless you add `-pedantic`. user3524728: Please update your question to show us *both* the complete source file you're compiling *and* the exact command you're using to compile it.

Answer (score 2):

though I tried to make my gcc yell about that, I couldn't succeed, but a quick look on the inter tubes made me find the following:

> warning: ISO C forbids nested functions
>
> Missing closing brace at end of a function.

from [http://users.csc.calpoly.edu/~jdalbey/101/Resources/errormessages.html](http://users.csc.calpoly.edu/%7Ejdalbey/101/Resources/errormessages.html)

update: thanks to @keith-thompson, I actually had the warning appear:

```
gcc -std=c99 t.c -o foo -Wall -pedantic
t.c:21:1: warning: ISO C forbids nested functions [-pedantic]
t.c:32:5: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input
```

for the following snippet:

```
bool looser () {

bool winner(char c,int n,char m[n][n]) {
    if(Line(c,n,m))
        return true;
    if(Column(c,n,m))
        return true;
    if(Radios1(c,n,m))
        return true;
    if(Radios2(c,n,m))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

hint: use a correct indentation in your code to find out where is the unmatched `{`

Comment: it was  missing a closing bracket (}). thanks :)

Comment: you're welcome! FYI, the Stack Overflow way of saying thanks is usually to accept an answer ;-) (if you still can as the Q is on hold)